# Combining discrete empirical distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, simulation

I'm running some simulation software and I'm currently in a bit of a pickle;

If I have two sets distributions, the first giving varying probability of 1...n events occurring, and the second giving the probability that each event takes a certain amount of time (i.e. 10/20/30 mins), how exactly would I combine these to create a distribution that gives the total amount of time spent?

For example, if the we randomly obtain 2 from the first distribution, the total time would be (10/20/30) + (10/20/30) minutes depending on probability.

How would I generalise this for the entire set of data?

Comment: Are you asking how you would calculate the probability that the total amount of time spent is (for example) 1000 minutes? It would help if you explained in more detail what you tried and why it's not good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you'd do best to model this as a random sum of
random variables. Here is an example.

Suppose a search procedure requires $N + 1$ searches, where
$N \sim Pois(\lambda=5).$ Also, times for individual searches can be
modeled as $X_i \sim Exp(rate = 1/50)$ so that $E(X_i) = \mu = 50$ units of time.
Then the total length of time for a search is $T = \sum_{i=1}^{N+1} X_i.$
You may be interested in $P(T > 600).$

Assuming that $N$ and the $X_i$s are all independent, standard probability
formulas give $E(T) =  (\lambda + 1)\mu = 300,$ which is straightforward,
and $$V(T) = \sigma_T^2 = E(N+1)\sigma_X^2 + V(N+1)\mu_X^2,$$ so
$\sigma_T = 165.8312,$ which may be surprising because of the second term for
the variance.

A simulation in R shows that $P(T > 600) \approx 0.0533 \pm 0.0004.$ A normal approximation based on mean 300
and SD 165.83 is inappropriate because the distribution of $T$ is
skewed. But my main concern is that trying to combine summarized values of
$N$ and $X$ from observed data may not give you a 
realistic view of the actual variability of $T.$

```
m = 10^6;  lam=5;  bet = 1/50;  t = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
 n = rpois(1, lam);  t[i] = sum(rexp(n+1,bet))
}
mean(t);  sd(t);  mean(t > 600)
## 299.7921  # aprx E(T) = 300
## 165.8158  # aprx SD(T) = 165.83
## 0.053278  # aprx P(X > 600)
```

Here is a histogram of the simulated distribution of $T$ along with
a (preposterously bad) normal density "fit."

[image]